# What is the intuition for why the determinant of a matrix is the product of the pivots in the matrix after gaussian elimination?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I'm trying to connect the calculations for the determinant I'm seeing and the idea that the determinant is a signed measure of the factor by which the volume bounded by the basis vectors of a vector space changes when those basis basis vectors are acted on by a linear transformation. Does anyone have a good way of connecting this geometric intuition with the way matrix determinants are computed, specifically with the "product of pivots" method I refer to in the title to this post?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give an explanation, because what you said is not true. Here is a counterexample:

$$
\det
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\right)=0\neq1\times1.$$